# Newtonsoft.json - I could not use it in SSIS package - An Error Occured

Tags: c#, json, rest, ssis, json.net

I am developing an SSIS project.

Environment: VS 2010

Installed newtonsoft.json by using **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json {Your Project Name} 6.0.3** comment line.

My code:

```
    static String BasicIOCommunication(String Url, String Data, String AuthendicationHeader, string Content_Type, string Method)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        request.Method = Method;
        request.ContentType = Content_Type;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthendicationHeader);

        WebResponse myWebResponse = request.GetResponse();          

        string jsonString = null;           

        //Set jsonString using a stream reader
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {

            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\\", "");
            reader.Close();
        }
        return jsonString;           
    }
```

Main Class

```
    public void Main()
    {

        //Authentication
        string URL = "";
        string Authendicationpath = "";           
        string Content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string AuthenticationURL = URL ;
        string AuthenticationMethod = "GET";

        string reponse = BasicIOCommunication(AuthenticationURL, DATA, Authorization, Content_type, AuthenticationMethod);
        if (reponse != "False" && reponse != null)
        {
            var TranactionObj = JObject.Parse(reponse); 
        }
      }
```

If I add this line, `var TranactionObj = JObject.Parse(reponse);` I am getting a below error.

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: Are you facing this problem while running in visual studio or In deployment server?

Comment: In Visual Studio. While running a script I am getting this error.